# Store a css class into a cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cookies

I would like to know how i can store the hide() method into a cookie and expires in a year

Hide is hiding my div tag I have  with an  tag onclick="removeThis(this);"

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
  function removeThissearch(field)
  {
    $(field).parent().hide();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Cookies should not be used for storing CSS classes.

Comment: Just set a cookie, any cookie. If it exists, hide your div.

Comment: Sorry, but I think that your question has a lot of issue with it, including the wording of the question itself, which is confusing and implies that you need to look into certain javascript principles (domready, localstorage, cookies, showing and hiding) before we could even begin to get you where you want to go...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to store a value into a cookie rather than a whole method.

Then depending on the value of the cookie (or whether it simply exists) you'll know whether to show the field or not by checking the cookie value when the page is loaded.